# Swap key and label in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot like this:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggtext")

df = data.frame(x = rnorm(n=12), y = rnorm(n=12),
                groupshape = rep(c("a","b","c"), 4),
                groupcol = rep(c("e","d","f"), 4))

p = ggplot(df, aes(x = x,y = y, 
               shape = groupshape, 
               color = groupcol)) + 
  geom_point() + theme_classic() + labs(shape = "shape", color = "color")
```

Producing a plot like this:

[image: Boring Scatterplot]

But I want to know how to get something like this with the legend:

[image: Super Cool Scatterplot]

How would I do that? I can get rid of the shape itself through `guides` by turning them all while, but then the text just hovers menacingly without alignment to the legend below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved via the `label.position` and the `label.theme` arguments of `guide_legend`:

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("ggtext")

df = data.frame(x = rnorm(n=12), y = rnorm(n=12),
                groupshape = rep(c("a","b","c"), 4),
                groupcol = rep(c("e","d","f"), 4))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x,y = y, 
                   shape = groupshape, 
                   color = groupcol)) + 
  geom_point() + theme_classic() + labs(shape = "shape", color = "color") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(label.position = "left", label.theme = element_text(face = "bold")),
         shape = guide_legend(label.position = "left"))
```

[image]

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that already. Before it was such that only the middle element swapped locations and the red and blue labels stayed where they were. I wonder what I actually did... Anyways, thank you!!